# Razor view model binding use javascript function

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

I have following model binding in reazor view .cshtml

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.cDate,
    new{
        @id = "textd",
        @type = "text"
    }
)
```

I want to call a javascript function before binding like below

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => updatedateFormat(m.cDate),
    new{
        @id = "textd",
        @type = "text"
    }
)
```

*updatedateFormat* is a javascript function.

I do have many options to do with c# only, But I am curious to know can we use javascript function with model binding.

I tried like below

```
@{
  string ccDate= @Convert.ToString("updatedateFormat(@Model.cDate)");
}
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => ccDate,
new
```

But not working

Please advise.
Thanks

Comment: No I change it in c# controller only

Answer (score 0):

Since it is not possible to trigger a `Javascript` function, when an input element or any other `html` element is rendered, you can use the `document.ready` event to achieve what your want:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m =>m.cDate,
    new{
        @id = "textd",
        @type = "text",
    }
)
```

And when the document is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ccDate= document.getElementById('textd');
    updatedateFormat(ccDate);
})
```

Or you could add a custom attribute such as `data-onload` to simulate a on load event:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.cDate,
    new{
        @id = "textd",
        @type = "text",
        data_onload="updatedateFormat('@Model.cDate')"
    }
)
```

And when the document is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[data-onload]').each(function(){
    eval($(this).data('onload'));
  });
})
```

If you only want to format the value of your property, you can do that using `ToString()` function inside the HTML helper:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m =>m.cDate,
    new{
        @id = "textd",
        @type = "text",
        @Value = Model.cDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
    }
)
```